# How to create .exe in visual studio 2005 windows based application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm unable to create correct `.exe` using **Visual Studio 2005** for a Windows based application in vb.net.

I can find after project build, a `windows installer` and a `setup` file. But after clicking on Windows installer (`.msi`) file, I was going through a wizard and finally with successfully completed. But when I click on `.exe`, it saying windows is now checking the problem. Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Have you checked in the bin folder?

Comment: I find nothing in Bin folder. I have Debug & Release folder. I got this .msi & setup file in Debug folder.

Comment: Did you look in the bin folder of both the main project and the setup project?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, you have built an application in VB.Net 2005 and your deployment project has successfully created an .msi file for installing the program.  When you execute the .msi to install your program, the .exe that it creates does not work?

I'm sure that you've debugged your application since you've already created an installer for it, so I doubt the issue is with your program.  I would guess it's one of the following 2 issues:

1.) You mentioned that you only find those files in your Debug folder and that there isn't anything in your Bin folder.  Have you built a Release version of the program yet?  If I remember correctly in VS 2005, there is a drop-down for Debug or Release.

2.) Just because the installer created an .msi file, it doesn't mean that it's a good one.  I think you should look into your installer from top to bottom as one or more of the settings are probably wrong.

Comment: Hi Jason, I earlier did in "Debug" mode ( not worked). Now I checked and generated .msi & .exe in (Release mode). Though, it fails. Can you tell me any other way to generate it properly.